# Controller issues with spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce, spree

my controller:

```
class Spree::CollectionPagesController < Spree::StoreController

  def index
    @collection_pages = CollectionPage.all
  end

end
```

I get : uninitialized constant Spree::CollectionPagesController::CollectionPage

with:

```
class Spree::CollectionPagesController < Spree::StoreController

end
```

I get empty undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Because I'm doing     1 - @collection_pages.each do |collection_page| in views.

This is my model

```
module Spree
  class CollectionPage < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope order('position')

  end
end
```

I inspected in the console, with Spree::CollectionPage.all and its not empty.

also everything is working fine in admin, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to scope it.

```
Spree::CollectionPage.all
```

Comment: @railsdevmtl You may also wrap the code in module Spree block so the full qualification may be omitted.